# Storing Default Values for BooleanField() and IntegerField() in Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know as per the documentation the following fields do not take `allow_blank=True` and `allow_null=True`

```
BooleanField()
IntegerField()
```

I need to allow the client to not specify g or d (as per below) and to store the value in the DB as `None`.

```
g = serializers.BooleanField()
d = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is there any more information you'd like in either of the answers?

Answer (score 6):

The different options for handling of empty, blank and null fields are (necessarily) a little subtle, so its unsurprising that it sometimes trips folks up.

> I know as per the documentation the following fields do not take allow_blank=True and allow_null=True

That's incorrect:

- `IntegerField(allow_null=True)` is valid.
- If you want to allow null inputs for boolean fields you need to use the `NullBooleanField()` class.

You are correct that neither of them take `allow_blank`, as the empty string isn't going to be a valid value in either case.

---

> I need to allow the client to not specify g or d (as per below) and to store the value in the DB as None.

**You can either use** `IntegerField(default=None)` and `NullBooleanField(default=None)`.

In this case when the values are omitted they will be included as `None` in `serializer.validated_data`. You'll want to make sure you use `null=True`/`NullBooleanField` on the model field.

**Or** `IntegerField(required=False)` and `NullBooleanField(required=False)`.

In this case when the values are omitted they will not be included in `serializer.validated_data`, and the model field default will be used. You'll want to make sure you use `default=None` and `null=True`/`NullBooleanField` on the model field.

---

Note that there was a bug when using the Browsable API that empty fields in HTML input [did not get the default values set](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3130). This is resolved in [the upcoming 3.1.4 release](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3159).

The `initial` argument suggested in Edwin's answer can also be useful, but is for setting an value to be initially rendered in HTML form fields.

Answer (score 1):

Django Rest Framework Serializer has `initial` options to set the dafault value of a field.

```
g = serializers.BooleanField(initial=True)
d = serializers.IntegerField(initial=0)
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/

Comment: Won't this store as `True` and `0` instead of `None` like the question asked?

Comment: I did try your suggestion but even if I set it to 0 for the d, then I still get an error.